# Importing an initialize function

Tags: script#

I am trying to create the import project library for Office (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142185.aspx) in Script# for some apps that I want to create. One of the functions wants the following JS to be created:

`Office.initialize = function (reason) {/* initialization code */}`
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161139.aspx)

I have the office class, and I can create the initialize property with the IntrinsicProperty attribute. However, I cannot then access that property without being in another method.

```
public static void Initialize()
{
   Office.Intialize = delegate(InializationEnum initEnum)
   {
      ...
   };
}
```

`

Which produces the following JS

```
OfficeScript.initialize = function AgaveScript$initialize() {
    Office.intialize = function(initEnum) {
        ...
    };
}
```

which is not the JS I want created.

Is it possible to import a function like Office.initialize?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your S# imports shared?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your code to set Office.Initialize in the static ctor of the OfficeScript instead.

Btw, it would be interesting to do this Office import library in a way that could be consumed by others... as a shared import library.